# What does the Localization bot do?

Tags: support, chat, localization

What does the [Localization bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-401) do? It is in chat room.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It posts localization requests into the appropriate chat rooms to translate the texts on the language-specific sites.

Sample found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/). It links to Transifex, which is a localization service SE uses to put in the resources and their translations.